# List to Hashmap to create API

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have some method that return an object and a count, due to the following SQL request

```
public List<Sales> mostLoyal() {
    String queryString = "SELECT s, COUNT(s.saleId) as TotalNum FROM Sales s GROUP BY s.custId.custLastName ORDER BY TotalNum DESC";
    List<Sales> breakdown = em.createQuery(queryString).setMaxResults(10).getResultList();
    return breakdown;
}
```

I'm trying to transform this List into a Hashmap containing the object (s in the request) and the count. I've tried a lot of things but I can't figure for the life of me out how to do that.
The goal is to return this Hashmap into a json.

Comment: `I've tried a lot of things` -> such as?

Comment: Are you using hibernate?

Comment: What values does the Sales class hold ?

Comment: This question is answered/described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896979/change-list-to-hashmap-in-java

Comment: Robert: Too much thing describe. Lots of way to get the first and second element of my list.
michal: I saw but not sure it will help me.
leo: I can get the first element from my class. But not the count, it's created by the request.
vidit: yeah

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through your list and place values in HashMap and return it. Should be simple.

```
public Map<String,Integer> mostLoyal() {
    Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    String queryString = "SELECT s, COUNT(s.saleId) as TotalNum FROM Sales s GROUP BY s.custId.custLastName ORDER BY TotalNum DESC";
    List<Sales> breakdown = em.createQuery(queryString).setMaxResults(10).getResultList();

    for(Sales sale: breakdown){
      m.put(sale.getS(),sale.getCount());

    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: No cause I don't have method getS() or getCount().

Comment: What does getResultList() method do then? , your Sales class must retain that info.

Comment: It's a method from the ORM.